# Compress and delete at the same time

Tags: p7zip

I'm using the command p7zip to compress files. There is not enough space on the disk even to store the compressed file. I'm compressing a directory where there are thousands of file, is there any way of compressing and deleting files at the same time so as to be able to do the compression with the limited space, or is there any other solution ?

Comment: If you have the room to compress one file at a time, you can use `gzip`, which will delete the source file by default once the compressed copy has been created.

Comment: yes I do have room for one file, what are the options for doing this ?

Comment: `cd /path/to/tonsofiles; gzip *`

Comment: The thing is that I have several subdirectories in the parent directory which i want to compress

Comment: `find /path/to/tonsofiles/ -type f -exec gzip "{}" \;`